# Windows GitLab Runner not able to identify mvn commands

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run simple Selenium test cases using Gitlab pipeline.
However when trying to run I am getting below error.

mvn : The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

My .gitlab-ci.yml file is as below
image: maven:latest

stages:

- test

variables:
MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

test:
stage: test
allow_failure: true

## Run the tests

script:
- mvn clean package
- mvn compile test

## Store artifacts

artifacts:
when: always
name: "report"
paths:
- target/surefire-reports/*
expire_in: 1 h

I have also set up MAVEN_HOME variable in System Variables and in PATH too
Also tried adding below line in config.toml file

environment = ["MAVEN_HOME=..../apache-maven-3.9.1/bin"]

Comment: to execute maven you would need to make sure that the image you use for the gitlab stage "image: xxxx" has maven preinstalled in the docker image. if you use an image where maven isnt present then you would definitely get this error as the stage would run in a container where there is no maven installed on the docker image.